# Dual monitor, two different desktops?

Tags: multi-monitor, fluxbox, virtual-desktop

If have two different monitors, both connected to the same integrated graphics 
card, one using VGA and the other using DVI connection.

It looks like this in my room:

```
######################     #############################
#                    #     #                           #
#                    #     #                           #
#        VGA-0       #     #           DVI-0           #
#                    #     #                           #
#      Monitor A     #     #         Monitor B         #
#                    #     #                           #
######################     #############################
         __#__                         __#__
```

I'm using Arch Linux / Fluxbox, and have 6 basic virtual desktops setup inside 
Fluxbox.

Currently my screen layout config is quite the default, the 2 monitors just 
form a larger desktop, where the mouse can navigate transparently.

I just run `$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --output DVI-0 --auto --right-of 
VGA-0` to swap the ordering of screens.

#### Question

Is it possible, instead of a large virtual desktop covered by the 2 monitors, to 
switch independently to a different virtual desktop in each monitor?

For example, "Monitor A" would display the virtual desktop 1, while "Monitor B" 
would display the virtual desktop 3.

I'm looking for CLI solutions, compatible with Fluxbox.

Comment: (a) are both monitors the same resolution; (b) does each monitor need to be able to display an arbitrary virtual desktop, or does desktop 1 and 2 only ever go on A, and 3 and 4 only ever go on B; (c) is the *same* virtual desktop displayed on *both* monitors permitted?

Comment: @derobert: (a) they're not the same resolution, but I put it as an auxiliary problem; (b) i'd like it to be arbitrary; (c) it should be permitted : i'm looking for "independency" so it should not be a problem

Comment: @derobert: indeed, because the resolution is different, I may reserve some desktops for one or the other monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a limitation of fluxbox, is not multihead ready because it's a lightweight and simple window manager, try switching to xmonad, spectrwm, or openbox-multihead-git (AUR). Those WMs will give you the options you're looking for.